# 100W LED going dim/bright/dim/bright every second after 10-15 seconds of power

Tags: led

I have a 100W LED chip which I have plugged into a 400W ATX PC power supply.  I am using a DC step-up converter (10-32v to 12-35v at 150W, 16A max in, 10A max out) to bring the 12V->30V to power the LED (30-34 volts are recommended.)

At 26V or less, I get stable light from the LED.  When I start to go higher, after 10-15 seconds of power it starts going dim for a second, then back to full brightness, then dim and so on.

What I'm trying to figure out is whether this would be a problem with the LED, the step-up converter, or the power supply. Can anyone give any suggestions on either what it might be, or on what tests I could run to figure out the problem?

Comment: Could be any one of them so, what extra information could you release into your question that might help someone narrow this down? Think about what this site is all about.

Comment: I am very new to circuits and their design and this is one of my first projects I'm playing with. That's why I was hoping for suggestions on how I might test where the snags are, to get more information. :)

Comment: With the information you have provided, it cannot be drilled down any further. My best guess is that it's the DC-to-DC converter.

Comment: it's the step up converter overheating. see if a fan affects the timing to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest monitoring the current flow. You've not specified what the rating of the DC-DC converter is, but in order to get the full 100W out you'll need something like 10A going in to it. What you might be seeing is either the PSU or converter hitting a current limit, going into safety shutdown, and then turning back on again.

Note that if you actually want to run a 100W LED unit at 100W the light is *extremely* bright and the unit will get hot, so you need to think about mounting it to a heatsink.

Comment: I have the LED mounted on a CPU heat sink/fan for heat control, I'm working on making a homemade projector right now so the extreme brightness will then pass through an LCD which will probably cut it in half thanks to polarization (from 10000 lumen to 5000 lumen if the chip specification is right) which will hopefully be a nice happily viewable image.

Also added in specifications for DC-DC converter to original post.

Comment: I will check current flow as soon as I get home from work today; would it make sense to check it both between the power supply and the converter and the converter and the LED?  Am I looking for spikes or drops in voltage basically?

Comment: Yes, might as well try both sides. See whether it shows signs of exceeding the allowed maximum. What's the maximum allowed from the ATX side?

Comment: I'd have to check when I get home for my specific model, I literally pulled it out of a closet  after years of it collecting dust but I just googled a couple of 400W ATX supplies and it looks like the 12v on them is either 25A or 30A.

Answer (score 1):

One problem you've got is that you are trying to control an LED by varying the voltage.

LEDs are best regulated by controlling the current.

The rating of your LED (kind of) indirectly tells you that.  It is a 100 watt LED with an operating voltage between 30 and 34 volts.  Somewhere in that range of voltage, it will draw enough current to consume 100 watts of power.

The exact voltage it takes will vary with several things.  The forward voltage of the LED will vary from unit to unit, and the forward voltage will vary with temperature.

Somewhere in the documentation for your LED will be a current rating.

What you need is a constant current regulator that can output up to 34 volts at the rated current.  The regulator doesn't vary the voltage to get the current right.  It limits the current the set level.  The voltage across the LED takes care of itself - as long as the maximum voltage from the current limiter is above the forward voltage of the LED.

You need to boost your 12V to about 34V, then limit the current to the rated limit for your LED.

The current limit will be around 2.5 to 3 amperes given a supply voltage of over 30V and a power rating of 100 watts.

---

I think what's going on is that your powersupply is protecting your LED (lucky you.)

The LED needs around 3A, but you aren't limiting the current.  As you turn up the voltage, the LED draws more than 3A.

To get 30V, you are boosting 12V with a boost converter.

To get 30V at 3A out (90 watts,) the boost converter takes in 12 V and at least 7.5A (also 90 watts) - and probably more because it has to make up for losses (waste, inefficiency) in the boost converter.

As you turn up the voltage and the current goes up, either the boost converter or the power supply hits a limit on the amount of current it can deliver and shuts down or reduces its output.

With lowered voltage, the current drops a little.  The power supply or booster recovers, and starts putting out full power again.  Repeat, and blink.

You are lucky enough that somewhere in your setup something isn't capable of delivering the current you asked of it, and saved your 100 watt LED from self destructing.

Comment: This is where I get confused. As I'm trying to read up on this now, some posts and responses on Stack Exchange seem to say that LEDs don't pull more amps than they need. Others were saying they'd burn out. You're saying my power supply or DC converter had a safety feature that saved my LED, which means I can't. The response before yours, also from someone with 40k reputation, seems to have no problem with this. Very confused.

Comment: Not so much a safety feature as that either the powersupply or the voltage booster wimped out (wasn't powerful enough) and saved your bacon.

Comment: Bare LEDs will pull as much current as you give them and burn out if you give them enough.  LED light bulbs (like you put in a plain old light socket) have current limiting built in so that Joe Blow can screw it into a regular socket and have it just work.

Comment: Your question mentions an LED chip, which I take to mean that it is bare - it doesn't have current limiting and that your circuit is responsible for safe operation of the LED.  This is backed up by the voltage range.  Ranges are typical of LEDs that expect to be operated from a constant current source.

Comment: A link to the datasheet of the LED would clear up a lot of the uncertainty.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense then.  This is the chip:  https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B01DFDKH2E/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 

It didn't come with a datasheet unfortunately.

Comment: It does look like just the bare chip.  Rated for 3A of current.  Similar LEDs are sold with a separate power supply that limits the current.

Comment: You need a 3A limit to your booster output.

Comment: Interesting, so if I use Ohm's Law to find out a needed resistance, I come up with V/I=R, 30V/3A=10, so then would a 10 Ohm Resistor protect the LED?

Comment: At 3A, I'd rather use a current regulator than a resistor.

Comment: And, no, a 10 ohm resistor won't do.  You need \$R_{series} = \frac {V_{supply} - V_f}{I}\$

Comment: For that to work, \$V_{supply}\$ must always be higher than \$V_f\$.  That means more than more than 34V.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113552/discussion-between-john-s-and-jre).

Answer (score 0):

Let us think

- takes 15 seconds for a mass of metal to heat up to the "too hot" temperature
- then cycles off and on and off and off
- FACT the thermal time constant of a cubic meter of copper is 9,600 seconds
- thermal time constant of cubic decimeter of copper is 96 seconds
- thermal time constant of cubic centimeter of copper is 0.96 seconds
- other metals will have similar response times
- silicon has 11,400 seconds TAU for a cubic meter

Comment: 1.  You are positing that some temperature protection is kicking in.  2. The time constants are interesting, but don't do anything to help explain why the LED brightness varies.

Comment: So this could also be caused by overheating?  I've just measured the temperature of the LED, it seems to hold steady at 80 Celsius with the CPU heat sink/fan combination I'm using.  Is that beyond a good temperature for it?